# What's a good way to learn microcontrollers without magic?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, arm, programming

I know software (C, C++, POSIX, assembly) and would like to learn microcontrollers at a low level, down to digital circuits.  I don't want to use any tools that obscure the internals, such as Arduino, mbed, or HAL, but want to understand down to the metal.

As described in [How should I debug this ARM Cortex M STM32 UART write?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/680329/how-should-i-debug-this-arm-cortex-m-stm32-uart-write), I decided to do this by writing code from the ground up, using no external anything, working out the details from the datasheets (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/680329/how-should-i-debug-this-arm-cortex-m-stm32-uart-write) for sample code).  However, [some have suggested](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/680329/how-should-i-debug-this-arm-cortex-m-stm32-uart-write?noredirect=1#comment1811450_680329) that this is not a good path to learn.

My goal is, BTW, to *learn*.  I'm not trying to produce any device that will actually have a practical purpose.

So: What is a good way to learn microcontrollers from the ground up, without any magic, wizards, or "trust me, click here and let the GUI/IDE do what's needed"?

Comment: Start by learning microprocessors. Making a little 6502-based computer kit can be really educational. And it's possible to make your own processor on a breadboard; there are kits to do that as well.

Comment: Theres not really much fundamental low-level difference between a microcontroller and a cpu - if you're looking to understand "down to digital circuits" then I would suggest learning how a basic cpu works, and then learn assembly. Once you understand that, then you can add the various peripherals that make it into a microcontroller

Comment: If by "down to metal" you actually mean "programming in a high level language (like C) but without a HAL" (which seems to contradict the digital circuits bit), then you should just keep doing what you're doing, but try to add way more comments, and look at how the HAL libraries are written to try to learn some better programming patterns. What that person was saying about "magic numbers" was referring to things like " GPIOA->MODER |= 2*BIT(3) + 1; " It's very unclear what this means. Look at things like #defines and the way they're used in HALs

Comment: "Down to the logic level" is several layers deeper than what was recommended to you in the comment you link to

Comment: Aduino uno is cheap heardware, but you don't have to use their firmware. get a USBasp programmer, and install the AVR toolchain on your computer and have at it.

Comment: In order to learn how C code translates to machine code, you need two things first: a solid grasp of C programming basics and a little bit of assembler knowledge. Then you can start learning how to use a disassembler to inspect what the compiler created out of the C source, which is often necessary when doing low level programming in C.

Answer (score 2):

STM32 are 32-bit microcontrollers (MCUs). They are very complex devices that challenge even veterans when first learning them. Perhaps you should try 8-bit (like PIC16/18) or 16-bit (like PIC24) devices first. I only mention these Microchip parts because I'm familiar with them. There are several manufacturers to choose from. There is no need to be an expert on these devices but once you know enough of the basics you can jump to 32-bit parts like STM32... and stay with single core devices first.

Good luck.

Comment: What you wrote is a good summary of what was in my mind when reading the question. I would also specifically recommend the PIC parts -- and perhaps the PIC16F84 may be best since it has been around for a very long time (before 2000) and lots of work has been done on them and they are easy to use. Microchip is also good because they are just plain a good company to be working with, all around. I also like other MCUs. The TI MSP430 has some wonderful counter/timer systems that beats much else out there and 16 bit is nice. But might be a bit too much to start out on. Anyway for spot-on writing +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the bare metal at the lowest possible level, start with a low end PIC MCU and write your code in assembly. The learning curve for this actually isn't too bad, since the instructions are fairly simple and intuitive. This is actually the way I started. You should understand going in though that using assembly in the modern world will handicap your productivity.

The next best option would be to use C on a low end MCU, but no libraries. Just write all your own code to interact with the peripherals. This is the route I'd recommend taking. You still control almost everything manually at the register level, but you can take advantage of loops, fuctions, etc to organize your code and make it more compact. Honestly this is often necessary even for people who don't want to get their hands dirty. The prepackaged libraries that come with MCUs are often sorely lacking.